# SQL : averaging values on one column for unique entries of another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a table with columns:

```
a CHAR, b Int, c Int
```

Column a only has entries of x/y/z, and the values in b and c go from 1 to 10.

Then I do:

```
select a, c 
from mytable 
where b > 5
```

What would I have to do from here to get a table of 3 rows (one for each letter), and the average c value for each of x, y and z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `group by`?

```
select a, avg(c)
from t
where b > 5
group by a;
```